# Spring integration ftp get entire file in custom filter

Tags: spring-integration

I have an application which picks up files using ftp inbound channel adapter. I have been unable to use the acceptoncefilefilter with it. Due to this I can check the file against my own stored data. The data is the sha key for the file.

My problem with this is that the customfilefilter I have used gets only the FTPFile, not the actual file. Hence I am unable to generate the SHA key for it.

This is the relevant configuration

```
    <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="c:\DMSRoot"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    remote-directory="DMS"
     preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true"
     filter="compositeFilterRemote">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="DMS" 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
     temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
    <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="new File(payload).delete()" />
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="new File(payload).delete()" />
          </bean>
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
  </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
    <bean id="compositeFilterRemote" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Ensures that the file is whole before processing it -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />
                <bean class="com.polling.util.CustomFileFilterRemote"/>
                <!-- Ensures files are picked up only once from the directory -->

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    public class CustomFileFilterRemote implements FileListFilter<FTPFile>
{

    @Override
    public List<FTPFile> filterFiles(FTPFile[] files)
    {
```

Please let me know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Please, be more specific. The `FTPClient.listFiles` returns exactly `FTPFile[]`. What do you mean regarding `the actual file` ?

Comment: The FTPFile is a reference right? it is not a file actually. I want the contents means the java.io.file to generate the sha key. I would like that to be done only using the info provided by the FTPFile

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch the file first to calculate the sha - there are two filters - one to decide whether we should fetch the file or not (we just receive file metadata - like from ls). After fetching the file, a second filter (`local-filter`) is used against the file system file.

Comment: so i dont do more than pattern eval in the filter and in the local-filter i add code to actually check the file maybe get the sha etc?

Comment: Right, but understand you are fetching the entire file every time; it might be expensive to keep fetching large files.